# How to get specific words from a text in Python?

Tags: python

I have a text, in fact an email, from my university like this:

```
FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF ABC

Name : Rodrigo Martins de Oliveira
RA: 11009713
Campus : Campus Santo André
Shift: Morning

weekly charge
=============
Credit (T-P) : 18
Load - time (T-P-I) : 44

Requested enrollment in the following classes :
=================================
  BC0208 - Mechanical Phenomenons A2-Morning (Santo André) - TPI (3-2-6) - Campus St. André
  Tuesday from 10:00 to 12:00
  Tuesday from 08:00 to 10:00
  Thursday from 08:00 to 10:00
  BC0504 - The Nature of Information A2-Morning (Santo André) - TPI (3-0-4) - Campus St. André
  Friday from 08:00 to 10:00
  Thursday from 10:00 to 12:00
  BC0306 - Transformations in Living Beings and Environment A1-Morning (Santo André) - TPI (3-0-4) - Campus St. André
  Wednesday from 08:00 to 10:00
  Monday from 10:00 to 12:00
  BC0402 - One Variable Functions A1-Morning (Santo André) - TPI (4-0-6) - Campus St. André
  Monday from 08:00 to 10:00
  Wednesday from 10:00 to 12:00
  BC0404 - Analytic Geometry A2-Morning (Santo André) - TPI (3-0-6) - Campus St. André
  Wednesday from 08:00 to 10:00
  Friday from 10:00 to 12:00


Code of authenticity : 4TlG58kWtrdN1caEJM02Ik8/C01p + qLeSFDOtXHZLMJrafv3H/soML2XPkrU pBHmBXBwMgRbd7Y =



Note : Document for simple conference, follow in the site the results of this enrollment request.

-
This email was sent automatically on Thursday, September 19, 2013 , 12:06 . Please do not reply .
If there are any technical questions , please contact via email xxxxxx@yyyyy.zzz
```

This email gives me the classes I requested enrollment and their respective timetables. I am writting a program to automatically get this info and make a table like this one:
[image: Timetable]

I am just starting to write this program and I need to get the code of the classes (`BC****`) and their respective schedules for me to plot the table.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you know about Python?

Comment: I am starting learning Python, I thought making a timetable program should be a good start.

Comment: If you start reading the Tutorial in the Python documentation and keep your problem in mind, I'm sure you will get lots of ideas.  Once you start, if you get stuck, post what you have and what went wrong.  Don't try to do everything at once - look at @Jacob's answer and see if you can figure out how it works.

Comment: @wwii Thanks, sorry for my hastiness. Will do as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the lines based on a new line, though this seems like a job for awk!! But in python

```
lst = text.split("\n")
#lst is of type list
for line in lst:
    if lst[:2] == "BC":
        #tadah, you know this line contains what you want do some magic
```

one caveat, it might be that there are some spaces preceeding the BC part, so tear that extra space out

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!